# Insert scatter chart has only 1 dot and the title is actually a value

Tags: excel, scatter

I'm sorry for the vague title, did not know how to title it otherwise. So I've got a huge set of data, about 7k lines. Basically, a table with 2 columns and 7000 lines. When I select the data + labels and go to Insert -> Scatter chart, only 1 point is shown on the graph, and the title of the graph is actually the last value. I've tried multiple fixes and no luck. Any ideeas?

Here's what it looks like: 
[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0yNZ.png)

Here's the spreadsheet if you need it (sorry it's on mega.nz, it's the only site that I know of that doesn't show popups etc.): [the spreadsheet](https://mega.nz/file/m1l3maDZ#VLK11qArcdFABMAtFj695yjx-4-qW7RMwepFU6o7YwM)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the graph type to the line and then returned it to what it was in the beginning it worked for me properly.

[image]